# Separate one column (with different formats) in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe in R with 91 columns and 51000 rows: the first column is the taxonomic classification of each organism that I found ('Classification'), and the remaining is the abundance in each sample ('S1', 'S2', 'S3', until 'S90'). I want to split the first column into six: columns 'K', 'P', 'C', 'O', 'F', and 'G'. The problem is that some of the cells have incomplete data, and, if I separate the cells using the semicolon, these cells will generate fewer colums than expected.

Current dataframe:

| Classification |
| --- |
| k__Bacteria |
| k__Bacteria;g__Streptofusia |
| k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae |
| k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae;c__Oligosphaeri;o__Oligosp;f__Ol |
| k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae;c__Oligosphaeri;o__Oligosp;f__Ol;g__Ol |

My question is: can I separate and organize my cells according to the suffix? I would like to have a column 'K' with all the information that starts with 'k__', a column 'P' with all the information that begins with 'p__', and so on. The empty cells could be filled with NA.

Ideal dataframe:

| K | P | C | O | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| k__Bacteria | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| k__Bacteria | NA | NA | NA | NA | g__Streptofusia |
| k__Bacteria | p__Lentisphaerae | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| k__Bacteria | p__Lentisphaerae | c__Oligosphaeri | o__Oligosp | f__Ol | NA |
| k__Bacteria | p__Lentisphaerae | c__Oligosphaeri | o__Oligosp | f__Ol | g__Ol |

Please, can someone help me with that?

I tried using the function 'separate' from the tidyr package.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `tidyr::separate_longer_delim` (requires `tidyr 1.3.0`) and a `pivot_wider` like so:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  separate_longer_delim(Classification, delim = ";") |> 
  mutate(suffix = toupper(substr(Classification, 1, 1))) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = suffix, values_from = Classification) |> 
  select(-row)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   K           G               P                C               O          F    
#>   <chr>       <chr>           <chr>            <chr>           <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 k__Bacteria <NA>            <NA>             <NA>            <NA>       <NA> 
#> 2 k__Bacteria g__Streptofusia <NA>             <NA>            <NA>       <NA> 
#> 3 k__Bacteria <NA>            p__Lentisphaerae <NA>            <NA>       <NA> 
#> 4 k__Bacteria <NA>            p__Lentisphaerae c__Oligosphaeri o__Oligosp f__Ol
#> 5 k__Bacteria g__Ol           p__Lentisphaerae c__Oligosphaeri o__Oligosp f__Ol
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Classification = c(
    "k__Bacteria",
    "k__Bacteria;g__Streptofusia", "k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae",
    "k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae;c__Oligosphaeri;o__Oligosp;f__Ol",
    "k__Bacteria;p__Lentisphaerae;c__Oligosphaeri;o__Oligosp;f__Ol;g__Ol"
  )
)
```

Comment: awesome. I still feel it is a bit involved, but could not make the likely more concise wider_regex work....

Comment: That was really useful, thanks! I just have a follow-up question: when I did this to my data, it worked, but instead of NAs, I am getting NULL. I also receive the following error: Warning message:
Values from `Classification` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
  dplyr::group_by(row, suffix) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L)

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you added the `mutate(row = row_number())` from my code? The reason I added this line of code was to prevent that error. But as similar issue might arise when we have duplicated `Classification`s per row in the original dataset, e.g. something like `"k__Bacteria;k__Bacteria"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `separate_wider_regex`, which is perfect for this use case. The magic occurs with the argument "patterns", which is a vector of optionally named elements. Unnamed elements are discarded (the semicolons in this case), but named elements are extracted to columns with their names.

```
library(tidyr) #version 1.3.0

separate_wider_regex( data = dat,
                      col = Classification,
                      patterns = c(K = "k_+\\w+",
                                   ";",
                                   P = "p_+\\w+",
                                   ";",
                                   C = "c_+\\w+",
                                   ";",
                                   O = "o_+\\w+",
                                   ";",
                                   F = "f_+\\w+",
                                   ";",
                                   G = "g_+\\w+"
                                   ),
                      too_few = "align_start"
                      )

# A tibble: 5 × 6
  K           P                C               O       F     G    
  <chr>       <chr>            <chr>           <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 k__Bacteria NA               NA              NA      NA    NA   
2 k__Bacteria NA               NA              NA      NA    NA   
3 k__Bacteria p__Lentisphaerae NA              NA      NA    NA   
4 k__Bacteria p__Lentisphaerae c__Oligosphaeri o__Oli… f__Ol NA   
5 k__Bacteria p__Lentisphaerae c__Oligosphaeri o__Oli… f__Ol g__Ol
```

*OBS:
As pointed out by @stefan, this is not quite right, as the output is missing a few values when the order of the patterns is changed.
It is definitely worth showing `separate_wider_regex`thoguh, so I am keeping this answer alive while I try to fix it.

Comment: Nice. But there is one issue. In the second row of the `G` column the `g__Streptofusia` is missing.

Comment: hum, you are right, I think my solution is sensitive about the order of the K-P-C-O-G elements... Will try to find a workaround.

Comment: Stil useful for me as you answer pointed me to the `too_few` argument. (: